# MobileFirst Cordova resolveLocalFileSystemURL() throws Error code 5

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

So I am working on our existing application which is a hybrid app created with IBM MobileFirst, Cordova in eclipse. Customer request a pdf file, the request goes to the server and brings binary which then we save as file. Everything was working upto ios version 11, but recently it started to throw error code 5 when it reaches here resolveLocalFileSystemURL(). It was working fine before sometime. Nothing in the code has been changed, I tried changing the directory, and possible everything on the internet to resolve the issue but still no luck. Any help is appreciated.

The path is returning "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[App UUID]/Library/myfile.pdf"

Code snippet below.

```
function localFilePath(filename) {
                if(device.platform.toLowerCase() == 'ios') {
                    console.log(cordova.file.documentsDirectory+ filename);
                    return cordova.file.documentsDirectory + filename;
                }
            } 
// save file to storage using cordova
            FileWritter.prototype.saveFile = function(data, ok, fail) {
            this.fileData = data;

            var path = this.filePath.substring(0, this.filePath.lastIndexOf('/'));

           var that = this;                

            // Write file on local system
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(directoryEntry) {
               var options = {create: true, exclusive: false};

               directoryEntry.getFile(that.fileName, options, function(file) {
                file.createWriter(function(writer) {                                 
                writer.onwriteend = function(event) {                                                                                        
                if(typeof ok === 'function') {
                    ok(event);
                }
             };
           writer.write(that.fileData);
         }, printObj(response));
 },  printObj(response));
},printObj);
};
```

Comment: Which version of MobileFirst are we talking?

Comment: MobileFirst version 7.1

Comment: You mention this stopped working "recently". Did the OS change to iOS 12? Or probably to iOS 11.x?

Comment: Yes exactly. As per my confirm knowledge it was working till ios 11 - 11.2 or something, but I have ios 11.4 - 12, which are not working, I think it is due to apple made some changes in ios releases and we are not updated accordingly, Which is not feasible right now.

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Checking on this.